# Junit exception handling in before

Tags: java, exception, junit, junit4

My question is, that I have no clue how to handle exceptions in the @before block of Junit4.
For example:

```
@Before
public void init() throws Exception{
    b=new FirstNationalBank();
    acc1=b.openAccount();
    acc2=b.openAccount();
    try{
    b.deposit(acc1, 1500);
    b.deposit(acc2, 12000);
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

The way I did this doesn't seem right, or maybe It is, but I am not sure, whether this will throw an error or how It will react when an unexpected exception or an exception of any kind gets thrown.

How would you handle It?

Comment: Catching an exception of any class, and then throwing an exception of the base Exception class (with no message) is not useful; all it accomplishes is the hiding of useful diagnostic information.

Comment: *but I am not sure*,    It is the work of moments to try it out.  (The framework will handle it).

Answer (score 1):

Catching and re-throwing is pointless here, and in this case you're losing the original stack trace that tells you what went wrong. Just let stuff be thrown:

```
@Before
public void init() throws Exception{
    b=new FirstNationalBank();
    acc1=b.openAccount();
    acc2=b.openAccount();
    b.deposit(acc1, 1500);
    b.deposit(acc2, 12000);
}
```

The test framework will catch and report any exceptions.

If you do need to catch something and rethrow, remember to pass the original Exception to the new exception, a throwable has a member called cause that can hold another throwable. That way you retain the original stacktrace that shows what happened.